# Path being drawn too far

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following path in a WPF application to try and draw a border on a rounded tab:

```
M6.5,2.6 C4.767,0.973 2.509,0 0,0 L0,0 0,19 L23,19z
```

Which renders to the red lines in the following image:

[image: Full image]

This however draws round the whole extended shape, as expected. So I decided to reverse the path to create the border only on the right hand edge to that the unwanted parts are not rendered as below:

```
M23,19 L6.5,2.6 C4.767,0.973 2.509,0 0,0z
```

Which renders as the following red lines in the following image:

[image: Border]

As you can see the line goes further than the bottom and right side of the tab control and wraps back to the start.

How can I fix this so that it renders correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `z` at the end.

`z` is the instruction to close the path, and you don't want that

Comment: It was as simple as that, thanks. How come it was extending to far though? That sent me on a wild chase.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Because the default MiterLimit is 10 (times line width or so). When your LineJoin is set to Miter, sharp turns (like in this case) will cause that.